Start a condition with specific text VBA
I have this code that doesn't work properly. For every row in column color its giving "Green" results. Could anyone help me find what's wrong with the code.
Example of the data:
Example



No
Fruit
Color




1
Mango



2
Apple



3
Tangerine



4
Durian



5
Cherry



6
Mango





    Sub warna()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Variant
    Dim vl As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set vl = ws.Range("B:B")

        For Each vl In rng
            Select Case vl.Formula
                Case "Mango": rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Green"
                Case "Apple": rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Pink"
                Case "Tangerine": rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Orange"
                Case "Cherry": rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Red"
            End Select
        Next vl
    End Sub



Because rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = ... always fills the complete range which is ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

You don't need to use Set v1 = ws.Range("B:B") if you're going to use it as the iterating cell in rng, use  v1.Offset(0,1).Value =  instead of the rng.Offset(0,1).Formula = 

I couldn't implement it properly should i change the Select Case v1.formula to value as well?

Yes, you can. I cannot understand why you used formula... Anyhow, it will return the value if no formula. But this will  not solve the implementation. You have to firstly understand the above comments... Do you? Anyhow, your code iterating through 1048576 rows will consume time and Excel resources for nothing. Place the formula (as formula) for all the range, or iterate between each cell for ones containing values...

The adjustment to your code as suggested in the comment
' Set vl = ws.Range("B:B")  <= not needed at all

    For Each vl In rng
        Select Case vl.value
            Case "Mango": vl.Offset(0, 1).value = "Green"
            Case "Apple": vl.Offset(0, 1).value = "Pink"
            Case "Tangerine": vl.Offset(0, 1).value = "Orange"
            Case "Cherry": vl.Offset(0, 1).value = "Red"
        End Select
    Next vl

rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula= "Green" will fill all cells in C2:C7 with Green and as the last iteration of the loop meets the condition Case "Mango" it fills the cells with Green.
